# Gemfile syntax error: <<<<<<< HEAD when trying to start localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, git, terminal, gemfile

I try to start my localhost:3000 RoR app. 
What is happening in Terminal:

```
[omrails]$rails s
Gemfile syntax error:
<<<<<<< HEAD
^
```

I tried searching on Google and on Stackoverflow, but didn't see any problems similar to mine. I assume something is wrong with ny Gemfile, but I have no idea what exactly.

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong in my Gemfile? 
Should you have any additional questions or reqs, do not hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This region:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
end
=======
# gem 'sqlite3'

>>>>>>> 154ef24b95ea600ced834457e146c2fb27a18156
```

Is a git merge conflict.  It says that there was a change in both the current version (HEAD) and another commit that you pulled (154ef24b95ea600ced834457e146c2fb27a18156).  The contents of the file that differ are presented in each region for your perusal.

When you get a conflict like this (usually by running `git merge` or `git rebase`, or `git pull`), then you are *supposed* to actually **fix** the conflict before doing `git add` to mark it as resolved.  You do this by looking at the two regions separated by the `=======` and decided which one to keep.

Sometimes you have to decide how to merge the two into one that does what both changes did, but in this case you probably just want to throw away the commented-out part. If you trim out the line starting with `<<<<<<<`, and everything between the `========` and `>>>>>>>>` lines, inclusive, then you should be good to go.

It might not hurt to study up on git merge and rebase procedures in general - they're powerful but can be a bit complex if you aren't familiar.

Comment: Okay I decided to keep `group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end` in my Gem file and I deleted the `<<<<<<< HEAD` and the `=======
# gem 'sqlite3'

>>>>>>> 154ef24b95ea600ced834457e146c2fb27a18156` parts, then I run `git add .` in Terminal, and then when I try to start my localhost I get `$rails s
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.` I'm very new to this, so please write me what to do in detail :)

Comment: @IlliaStrikhar After you add, you need to commit too.

Comment: @alex I commit, still no success: `[omrails]$git commit -m "init"
[master ae46cda] init
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
[omrails]$rails s
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.`

Comment: I copied and pasted your updated Gemfile into a new Rails project and had no trouble running 'bundle install', 'rails s', etc.  Are you using an old version of Ruby?  Normally I see line numbers in the output when there's an error in the Gemfile...  try running 'bundle install' in case it gives more meaningful output.  If all of that doesn't work, you've run into a problem that we cannot reproduce outside of your environment, which may be a clue in and of itself.

Comment: @BenjaminCox When I run 'bundle install' this is what i get in the beginning: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:64:in `parse_source': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`Maybe it can give you a clew what's going on..If no I'll reinstall the whole app

Comment: I suspect that deleting Gemfile.lock will help - running bundle install again will recreate it, but clean this time

Comment: @BenjaminCox I did what you said, then it asked me to install additional omniauth gems, and after that, it started! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have committed the result of a merge conflict in Git.

You need to remove those lines, and pay special attention to make sure the code is what you expect.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
end
=======
# gem 'sqlite3'

>>>>>>> 154ef24b95ea600ced834457e146c2fb27a18156
```

You can see what is in your current `HEAD` and what was in `154ef24b` at the time of the merge. Choose how you want to resolve it by removing the conflict markers and keeping/modifying the chunks either side.

Comment: Better suggestion will be, I think "Re-merge sources and use visual mergetools for resolving conflict"

Comment: Post your whole Gemfile and we'll post a version that's fixed

Comment: @BenjaminCox I did post it in the description.

Comment: @IlliaStrikhar If it still looks like that, then you haven't used any of the suggestions provided in the answers.

Comment: @alex My fault, sorry. Updated the file in the description.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, you've committed the results of a merge conflict in git.  You need more details on what he means when he says to pay close attention that the code is what you expect.  You don't want to just remove the conflict markers (the <<<<<<, ==========, and >>>>>>>>>>>), you need to actually resolve the conflict.

`HEAD` had the following when you did the merge:

```
group :development do  
gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And in the branch containing the commit you merged in (`154ef24b95`) you had:

```
# gem 'sqlite3'
```

This (appears to) mean that when the merge was done `HEAD` was using sqlite in development and commit `154ef24b95` had decided not to.  You definitely want to figure out which version you actually want in your project here.  Don't just delete the conflict markers.